# Example of two space curves parametrized by arc lenght with same normal vectors that are not congruent.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The idea is to find two curves $\alpha: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}, s \mapsto \alpha(s)$ and $\beta: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}, s \mapsto \beta(s)$ parametrized by arc lenght that have the same normal vectors, i.e. that $\mathbf{n}_{\alpha} = \mathbf{n}_{\beta}$ in every point, and there are not congruent, which means that there not exist a rigid motion between them.

Clearly, they cannot have the same curvature and torsion so, for example, I thought about an helix and a circle. This example is not good, as they clearly are not isometric, but composing an isometry with a traslation the circle can be mapped to the helix.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Composing an isometry with a translation"? What do you mean? I think you should think about the circle and helix some more, since you know explicitly what their principal normal vectors are.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the concept of rigid motion, as I thought that it was possible to compose the isometry with a translation, but the translation I used was time-dependent and no of a fixed vector, so that wouldn't be a rigid motion. And so, yes, the example of the circle and helix works.